# Context-free grammar for "member of"/set membership?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, natural-language-processing

I wonder whether context-free grammar (or what else?) can be used to implement "member of" structures, which describe that **something is a member of something**.

For example, I want to be able to infer the statement:

> **John Lennon** is in **Beatles**.

The inferring process should return True since in the grammar John Lennon has been defined to be a member of the Beatles. If John Lennon weren't defined to be found in Beatles, I'd want to return False.

It does not look like a typical CFG product. Or could it be?

Or what kind of parsing and/or formal language technique is usable for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "implement"? Model the syntax of writing these things down? Note that what you have there is essentially prefix-form function application with arbitrarily many parameters, that is something that is part of the syntax of many programming languages and easily modelled with CFGs. Is your real question, can I express the *semantics* I want alongside parse trees of CFGs?

Comment: I don't see where you see any "pattern matching". Can you explain? It seems to be that you are mixing syntax and semantics.

Comment: @mavavilj, parsing is all about syntax and nothing about semantic, your query seems a non-sequitur.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to model expressions of the form

```
(function A B1 B2 B3 ... BN)
```

with a context-free grammar.

That's clearly possible; note that the term itself almost directly corresponds to a regular expression, i.e. you do not even need the full power of context-free grammars.

Consider this, for example (written in something like EBNF):

```
fct_appl = "(" fct_name set_name atom_name+ ")"
```

Here, `X_name` are tokens or other rules. If you separate parser and lexer, they would be lexer rules. If there are no syntactic differences between identifiers, you can use this

```
fct_appl = "(" ident ident ident+ ")"
```

This applies only to functions with one atomic and one list-type parameter, of course. You could also generalize to this:

```
fct_appl = "(" ident+ ")"
```

In any case, the *semantics* have to be defined elsewhere.

---

It does not really matter if you use programming-language style syntax like above, or natural-language style syntax like this:

```
my_membership = ident "is a" ident
```

This is all you need. Whether it's pre-, post- or infix, whether you use `is a` or `∈`, these are all design decisions that mostly go away after parsing¹ the syntax. Translate your parse tree into an AST and the information you get is the same: A is a B.

---

1. Some nasty corner cases regarding ambiguity and left-/right-recursion may happen and depend on your choice of syntax.